How to pass THIS value to a data layer using Google Tag Manager?
I'm new to this but eager to learn. I am currently trying to pass a value (email address of a purchaser in my shop) to the Google Tag Manager via a data layer variable. SEE CODE HERE
Now I am not sure how I need to formulate this in Google Tag Manager so the data layer accesses it correctly.
I can not use code directly - I need to go through GTM because my website is hosted on a rather limiting plattform, but GTM integration works just fine.
My first try was just to go
emailAddress.value

I researched that I need to use ".value" to extract a value, and that I need to put in the entire path. So for this code, would it be
data-gtm-form-interact-id.emailAddress.value

?
I'm having trouble to understand where the "path" that I need to track down to get to the right value starts, and what to include.
Any help is very appreciated.

Best option in my opinion is to see the data layer tab in Tag Assistant. It'll give you a better view of the structure and it'll make it easier to create the data layer variable.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
